# Is it possible to get harddisc size using php or java?

Tags: java, php

I want to detect the harddisc size of my computer and if possible the the partitions informations(partition size, free memory, used etc).Is it possible in php/java?

Comment: both PHP and JAVA has a function to run a console utility.

Comment: The size of the hard disk or the size of the file system?  The two are markedly different, and depending on the computer could be very different.

Answer (score 2):

For PHP use `disk_total_space()` function.

For me, getting the total disk space for java is complicated. I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 2):

For Java, finding free disk space used to be a long-standing feature request. It was finally implemented for Java 6 aka Mustang.

You can now use `File.getFreeSpace()` and `getUsableSpace()`. See e.g. http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19527.html for explanations and examples.

For Java versions prior to Java 6, there is no (easy, cross-platform) solution, just some ugly hacks.

Note: This will give you the free space on the partition of the `File` instance. I don't know of any way to get a list of all partitions, at least not in pure Java. At any rate, this is a highly system-specific information, so probably not feasible in pure Java.

Maybe you could describe your problem in more detail, then we can possibly help.